# c++ binary tree address boundary error SIGSEGV

Tags: c++, binary-search-tree, segmentation-fault

im trying to organize a list of nodes into a binary tree for my current project. Wrote the code just like in the book but when flow is in the while loop about to initialise current pointer with the right or left leave, i get the address error. why is that?

here is the insert() fn:

```
template <class elemType>
void bSearchTree<elemType>::insert(const elemType& insertItem){

    binaryTreeNode<elemType> *current;
    binaryTreeNode<elemType> *trailCurrent;
    binaryTreeNode<elemType> *newNode;

    newNode = new binaryTreeNode<elemType>;
    assert(newNode != NULL);
    newNode->info = insertItem;
    newNode->lLink = NULL;
    newNode->rLink = NULL;

    if(root == NULL)
        root = newNode;
    else{

        current = root;

        while(current != NULL){

            trailCurrent = current;

            if(current->info == insertItem){

                cout << "The insert item is already in the list-";
                cout << "duplicates are not allowed." << insertItem << endl;
                return;
            }else if(current->info > insertItem)
                current = current->lLink;
            else
                current = current->rLink;
        }

        if(trailCurrent->info > insertItem)
            trailCurrent->lLink = newNode;
        else
            trailCurrent->rLink = newNode;

    }

    if(current->info != insertItem){

            totalNodes++;
        }
}
```

Comment: A good start would be to use a debugger to catch the crash in action, so you could locate where it happens, and examine what the values of all involved variables are at the time of the crash. You could also step through the code, line by line, to make sure it works as expected.

Comment: A hint though: At the end of the function, you dereference `current` either uninitialized or as a null pointer.

Comment: Also, it looks like you have a memory leak if the item is already in the tree.